# The view news.views.Comment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, html, django

I am making it possible to comment on the article and I have a problem "The view news.views.Comment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."
I tried to add HTTPresponse but nothing comes out where I have to else I return everything but still this error

views.py

```
def Comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comments(request.POST)

        name = request.POST['name']
        text = request.POST['text']

        context = {
                   'name': name,
                   'text': text,
        }

        if comment.is_valid():

            comment.save()
            return render_to_response(request, 'news/post.html', {'comment': comment})
    else:
        return render_to_response(request, 'news/post.html')
```

post.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'comment' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="{{ text }}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

{% for comment in object_list %}

<h1> {{ comment.name }} </h1>
<h1> {{ comment.text }} </h1>

{% endfor %}
```

forms.py

```
class Comments(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'text')
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    dates = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dates']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: When does the Error occur? Does the error occur when you submit a comment or when you are loading the page?

Comment: @NeIT What if `comment.is_valid()` return `False`??

Answer (score 0):

These is missing one response statement when request.method == 'POST' and comment is not valid.

```
def Comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comments(request.POST)

        name = request.POST['name']
        text = request.POST['text']

        context = {
                   'name': name,
                   'text': text,
        }

        if comment.is_valid():

            comment.save()
            return render_to_response(request, 'news/post.html', {'comment': comment})

        return render_to_response(request, 'news/post.html')
    else:
        return render_to_response(request, 'news/post.html')
```